# iCloud Keychain suggested password custom UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, keychain

Is there a way for keychain suggested passwords to work on custom UITextFields?

My signup scene:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You need to set the textContentType of the UITextField to UITextContentType.UITextContentTypeNewPassword (if you want Apple to suggest a password) or UITextContentType.UITextContentTypePassword (if you want the QuickBar of suggested passwords to show up). You can find the all different types here on [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view?language=objc).

There are also WWDC resources [Introducing Password AutoFill for Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/206/) from WWDC 2017 and [Automatic Strong Passwords and Security Code AutoFill](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/204/) from WWDC 2018.

Comment: Text content type is set for all fields including username and password, hence why it tried to suggest it. however I think the issue here is that it doesn't fit my custom textfield